# CSS: white-space: nowrap no funciona en Outlook

Tags: css, outlook

Desde [campaing monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/white-space/) he podido comprobar que `white-space: nowrap;` no funciona ni en outlook.com ni en la aplicación de Outlook para iOS.

He probado a usar la propiedad `mso-world-wrap: none;`, pero tampoco ha funcionado.

Qué propiedad puedo utilizar que tenga una función similar?

Gracias de antemano